# What happens if the filter of an Exception filter throws an exception

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

I have not worked in C# 6 yet but was wondering....

As the title says "What happens if the filter of an Exception filter throws an exception?". I guess the really answer is "The filter should be written in such a way that it never throws an exception.", but lets say it does. Will it be as if the exception happened inside the catch itself?

```
try
{
  throw new Exception("Forced Exception");
}
catch (Exception ex) when (MethodThatThrowsAnException())
{
  WriteLine("Filtered handler 1");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  WriteLine("Filtered handler 2");
}
```

Or

```
try
{
  throw new Exception("Forced Exception");
}
catch (Exception ex) when (MethodThatThrowsAnException())
{
  WriteLine("Filtered handler 1");
}
```

---

**Edit: Interesting Example**
This section was removed because of a bug in alleged volatileread upon which the example was based. Further investigation is required

Comment: Kind of shows why Hejlsberg didn't want to include exception filters until now.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos maybe he just wasn't involved anymore. C# 6 has a few dubious features that don't seem like the team is playing it safe anymore. The release doesn't remind of Anders.

Comment: There's a mention of this in a DotNetRocks [show](http://www.dotnetrocks.com/default.aspx?showNum=935), start at about 48 mins - basically Mads says Anders said (paraphrased) "What do I have to do so I never have to talk about them again?" - about 49:30.

Comment: @usr this release sets the stage for the upcoming functional assault -  pattern matching etc. A huge effort but only a "few" visible features. Not dubious, their purpose becomes clear in a functional context.

Comment: My theory on volatileRead's output:There is no way that these guys have implemented a C# compiler, so the output that it shows has to be legit. I tried to think about how it must have been implemented. As the site allows different entry points in different sections (e.g [UtitlitySnippet](http://www.volatileread.com/UtilityLibrary?id=1083) has test case names, I thought, it must be using reflection to invoke the Main (or other) method. I tried it in VS CTP6, and it gave me `"Exception in filter condition"` exception. Now that's super weird, Invoke() throws diff exception than a normal call :O

Comment: Behavior is dictated by the CLI spec, Ecma-335 chapter III.3.34.  Quote: "If
an exception is thrown inside the filter block, it is intercepted and a value of
exception_continue_search is returned."  In other words, the exception is ignored and works as if the when-expression returned false.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If there is an exception thrown within the filter, then that exception will be silently swallowed and the filter simply fails. This causes the original exception to go down the `catch` cases or ultimately end up being reraised upwards.

So the code calling the filter will not have a way to know that there was actually an exception within your filter method. Thus, it’s important to avoid conditions where an exception can be thrown to make sure that a filter doesn’t fail for this reason.

You can verify this using the following code on [volatileread.com’s C# 6 beta interpreter](http://volatileread.com/utilitylibrary/snippetcompiler):

```
public void Main ()
{
    try
    {
        try
        {
            throw new Exception("Original exception");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
            when (Test()) // `if (Test())` in older previews
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Caught the exception");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
    }
}

public static bool Test ()
{
    throw new Exception("Exception in filter condition");
}
```

This results in the *“Original exception”* appearing in the outer try/catch block.

---

#### Update

Since I didn’t understand the output from volatileread’s compiler when not using the outer try/catch block, I installed the MS Build Tools 2015 myself (which as of the time of this answer still uses `if`, not `when`) and tried it out. It turns out that when not using the outer try/catch, the “original exception” is still the one that causes the program to crash. So **it’s not the filter exception**. This seems to be a bug with volatile’s compiler.

Comment: If you are having trouble running the snippet on the site, make sure to check the box "c# 6 beta". Also an interesting read on the same site about this: [C# 6 Exception Filters and How they are much more than Syntactic Sugar](http://www.volatileread.com/Wiki/Index?id=1087)

Comment: This does not make sense since in my tests Test would throw the exception and that would be caught by the outer catch. I would rerun your code but for some reason volatileread.com’s C# 6 beta interpreter is not returning any results for C# 6 for me

Comment: As you can see in the answer I gave. The second experiment gave a NotImplementedException. Which would mean your example would have to print "Exception in filter condition"?

Comment: Also noticed, you need to change 'catch (Exception ex) if (Test())' to 'catch (Exception ex) when (Test())' as the syntax has now changed in the latest release. The volatileread site also seems to have upgraded to the latest version.

Comment: Poke. I just reran your code. With the new when notation. Your output is correct. However do me a favor and take out your outer try catch then I get System.Exception: Exception in filter condition. Why is that happening?

Comment: @Rahul Eh, when did that happen? xD This is really bleeding edge, huh? (It was still `if` when I posted the answer) Thanks ;)

Comment: Think the reason why I could not get an output for C# 6 for a while was because they were updating it as I was running code. Have you rerun your code yet poke without the outer try?

Comment: @Murdock I spent a bit of time getting the new preview compiler running on my own machine and it turns out that the behavior is actually consistent. So it seems that there is a problem with volatileread’s online compiler.

Comment: I am glad that its a bug. Would have been some serious craziness if that was the actual result

Comment: @poke I figured the site must be using reflection to invoke the Main() method, and tried invoking the function in your code snippet (in VS 2015 CTP6) using Type.Invoke() and to my surprise it gave me `Exception in filter condition` instead of `Original Exception`.

Answer (score 4):

You can try it out [here](http://volatileread.com/utilitylibrary/snippetcompiler?id=8634).

As @Habib correctly indicates, the filter simply gets skipped and it's as if it never existed. From that point on, the catch clauses work as they always have. The example above demonstrates this.

However if you change the second catch clause to a type that cannot catch whatever is thrown from your method, your program will crash because of an unhandled exception.

Spicy detail (bug): if you call the method encompassing the try-catch via reflection and a `when` clause throws an exception then it will be this exception that is considered unhandled and not the original one. More information [here](http://www.volatileread.com/Wiki/Index?id=2095).

Comment: This is not correct - "By having that 2nd clause that catches Exception it will swallow any kind of exception you throw from MethodThatThrowsAnException()" -. Exception in Exception Filter method will be ignored and it will only cause the filter to fail. The **original  exception**  is what gets propagated down.

Comment: @Habib: important distinction, thanks. I drew the wrong conclusion from the thrown Exception in the try-block. I've changed the wording of my answer and the accompanying example.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit: The oddness seems to be caused by a bug in volatileread. Please refer to poke's answer. The experiments below can not be trusted**

So I ran a few experiments that gave a few interesting results to shed some light on the issue.

Check using http://volatileread.com/utilitylibrary/snippetcompiler?id=7632

```
public void Main()
{
  try
  {
    throw new Exception("Forced Exception");
  }
  catch (Exception ex) when (MethodThatThrowsAnException())
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Filtered handler 1");
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Filtered handler 2");
  }
}

private bool MethodThatThrowsAnException()
{
  throw new Exception();   
}
```

> Prints out "Filtered handler 2"

```
public void Main()
{
  try
  {
    throw new Exception("Forced Exception");
  }
  catch (Exception ex) when (MethodThatThrowsAnException())
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Filtered handler 1");
  }

}

private bool MethodThatThrowsAnException()
{
  throw new Exception("MethodThatThrowsAnException");   
}
```

Prints out:

> Unhandled Expecption:  System.Exception: MethodThatThrowsAnException
>   at Program.MethodThatThrowsAnException()    at Program.Main()

Another interesting output for

```
   public void Main()
    {
      try
      {
        throw new Exception("Forced Exception");
      }
      catch (Exception ex) when(MethodThatThrowsAnException())
      {
        Console.WriteLine("Filtered handler 1");
      }
      catch (Exception ex) when(MethodThatThrowsAnException2())
      {
        Console.WriteLine("Filtered handler 2");

      }
    }

    private bool MethodThatThrowsAnException()
    {
      throw new Exception("MethodThatThrowsAnException");   
    }

    private bool MethodThatThrowsAnException2()
    {
      throw new Exception("MethodThatThrowsAnException2");   
    }
```

> Unhandled Expecption:  System.Exception: MethodThatThrowsAnException2 
>   at Program.MethodThatThrowsAnException2()    at Program.Main()

**So it seems like it tries to evaluated the first catch if it throws an exception it continues to the next catch. The first catch that does not fail and matches all conditions then handles the exception (BTW an exception of the type originally thrown in the try). However if the last catch that is of the type of the thrown error also throws an exception in the filter part then an Unhandled Exception is thrown of the type in the filter.**

**Edit:**
Note:

```
public void Main()
{
  try
  {
    try
    {
      throw new Exception("Forced Exception");
    }
    catch (Exception ex) when (MethodThatThrowsAnException())
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Filtered handler 1");
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
      Console.WriteLine("Caught");
      Console.WriteLine(ex);
  }
}

private bool MethodThatThrowsAnException()
{
  throw new Exception("MethodThatThrowsAnException");   
}
```

Outputs:

> Caught
>
> System.Exception: Forced Exception    at Program.Main()

**If you compare that with the second output... HOW THE HELL IS THAT POSSIBLE???**
In the second example MethodThatThrowsAnException is thrown but in the last example "Forced Exception" is caught

Comment: "HOW THE HELL IS THAT POSSIBLE???" - That is because exception from Method (filter) is ignored. and it is the *original* exception that is getting caught. Exception from the method would be completely ignored, it will just cause the filter to fail. There will be no trace of `Exception("MethodThatThrowsAnException");`

Comment: @Habib thats obvious but why. This seems inconsistent.

Comment: It may appear inconsistent, but the purpose of the filter is either pass or fail. But I agree, the exception in filter method should be raised and not ignored/swallowed.

Comment: @Habib the purpose of a try catch is to catch the exception being thrown. Since this is MethodThat... it should be the one being caught.

Comment: First thing is that exception from `MethodThatThrowsAnException` is ignored, completely ignored. Second, since the original exception is not caught in the inner catch block it is getting caught in the outer catch block

Comment: No... look at the second example and you will see that is false @Habib

Comment: in the second code snippet where you have just one `catch` block with filter, It is failing but with `An unhandled exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in Application.` If you look at the details in VS it is again `Forced Exception`, the original. Where are you trying your code ?

Comment: No look at the discussion with poke. Seems like it is a problem with  http://volatileread.com

Comment: @Habib: Exception filters execute in a context where it isn't really possible to start a new exception propagating outward, but in most cases there isn't really a whole lot they should be doing that could cause an exception to be thrown.  If one wants to log exceptions without catching them, I would suggest that the right approach is to use a filter to capture the exception and do the actual logging in the `finally` block, being mindful that it's possible that a `try` block might complete normally even after one or more of its exception filters have been invoked (a scenario which...

Comment: ...would likely indicate a problem worthy of attention).

Answer (score 0):

Exception raised in exception filter will be ignored and it will cause the filter to fail.

[Exception filters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4dy8x9k9(v=vs.71).aspx) are feature of CLR since v1.0. Eariler they were available with VB.Net an F#. **As far as swallowing/ignoring exceptions in filter method is concerned, that is also a defined behavior** and unlikely to change in recent future.

---

Original exception will move down to other catch blocks or will remain un-handled in case of not being caught by any.

Consider the following code example:

```
try
{
    throw new Exception("Forced Exception");
}
catch (Exception ex) if (MethodThatThrowsAnException())
{
    WriteLine("Filtered handler 1");
}
catch (IndexOutOfRangeException ex)
{
    WriteLine("Index Out of Range");
}
```

and the method:

```
static bool MethodThatThrowsAnException()
{
    throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("Index Out of Range");
}
```

Although the method is throwing `IndexOutOfRangeException` and there is a `catch` block in the caller code for that specific exception but the exception from the method will never make it to the caller. `IndexOutOfRangeException` from filter method will be ignored and since the original exception `throw new Exception("Forced Exception");` from the first line isn't handled anywhere, The program will crash because of Unhandled Exception "Forced Exception".

---

In your first code snippet, since you have a catch block for base `Exception`, your original exception from the first line `throw new Exception("Forced Exception");` will be caught and handled there. You will not notice the exception thrown earlier in the filter method.

---